# NoReverseMatch from Django: Form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

My application from an uploaded CSV File has to read header values and pass these headers into `ChoiceField` on the next screen.

On choosing the selected `ChoiceField` item, **I have to display this item back on the screen**.

After getting the file I made the file type as `global` so that I can access it from other methods. Now after submitting the uploaded file, instead of getting the screen with `ChoiceField` dropdown screen I am getting **NoReverseMatch**. What I am doing wrong?

[image]

1.visualize_view.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ expense_form.as_p }}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

2.simple_upload.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <input type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

3.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from uploads.core import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login', views.loginForm, name='loginForm'),
    url(r'^uploads/', views.simple_upload, name='simpleUpload'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^visualize_view/', views.visualize_view, name = 'visualizeView'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.AKASH_ROOT)
```

4.view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from uploads.core.models import Document
from .forms import ExpenseForm

def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        global myfile
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        return redirect(request, 'core/visualize_view.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'core/simple_upload.html')


def visualize_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        expense_form = ExpenseForm(request.POST)
        if expense_form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse(expense_form.cleaned_data['columns'])
        else:
            return HttpResponse("This form was not valid.")
    else:
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        for row in myfile:
            headerlist = row.decode('utf-8').split(",")
            break
        expense_form = ExpenseForm(headerlist)
        return render(request, 'core/visualize_view.html', {'expense_form': expense_form})
```

5.ExpenseForm.py

```
from django import forms

class ExpenseForm(forms.Form):

     def __init__(self, headerlist, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExpenseForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        CHOICES = [(i, header) for i, header in enumerate(headerlist)]
        columns = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. You've redefined the Form init method to accept `headerlist` as the first argument, which you then use to generate the choices for the field. And you pass `headerlist` in your view. But you don't pass any actual *data* to validate; so the form can't ever be valid. Where is the data supposed to be coming from?

Comment: I have a `simple_upload.html` view binded with `simple_upload()` method. It carries a file uploader and a submit button in it. This page uploads the file. I will update the file.

Comment: But that didn't answer the question at all. The file appears to just be the header which determines the values of the choice field. Where is the actual data for the form?

Comment: I am sorry, could you help in further describing/elaborating about this actual data.. I am sure I am missing something significant.

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear. The point of a form is to allow the user to enter data. What data is being entered, and where?

Comment: The user only enters data at a login page, post I intend to display upload file page. User upload file, file gets parsed and displays headers under the 3rd visualize page. I dont have any other field/place for collecting user detail

Comment: How does the _actual_ data looks like

Comment: Updated the question and code.